# Aligning navigation button with left border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a side navigation button bar. When I click one of the buttons the icon's position changes as there is a border in the div. How can we set the icons on the same vertical line when the border is in the clicked button?

In the picture below I wanted to have the "Test Manager" button in the same red line.

Here is the HTML for one of the buttons:

```
<a href="/testmanager">
<div class="is-active action-button">
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">content_paste</span>Test Manager
</div>
</a>
```

And CSS for the button:

```
.action-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #526069;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.action-button.is-active {
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 4px solid var(--branding-color);
}

.action-button:not(.is-active):hover {
  background-color: #E9F1FA;
}
```

[image: Alignment changes when the button is clicked as there is a border of 4px on the left]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be something like this:

```css
.action-button {
    /* other rules... */
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
.action-button.active {
    border-left-color: var(--branding-color);
}
/* other rules... */
```

So now you will always have a border, hovering or emphasizing it would not change the layout.

But this has side effect: all text and icons will be aligned a little bit right (roughly 2px).
If you want them to be "truly" center, you may add another rule:

```css
.action-button {
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: So there will be a 4px border on right and left of the div?

Comment: There will always be a 4px border on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue would be fixed by adding

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
```

to your `.action-button` class.

This will make the calculation of the width including the border and therefore it will center it without minding the border.